# Beautiful Soup Obtain number of td class

Tags: python, class, html-table, beautifulsoup

I am trying to obtain the number of td class with "name table-participant" from the mentioned web without success, as I'm getting 0.
Any help?

Thank you

```
from requests import get
url = 'https://www.oddsportal.com/soccer/spain/laliga/'
response = get(url)

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
html_soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')
type(html_soup)

movie_containers = html_soup.find_all('td', class_ = 'name table-participant')
print(type(movie_containers))
print(len(movie_containers))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nothing wrong with your code, actually, but you didn't check the status code from the `GET` request. What is happening is that the server is replying with a nice `404`, and a page which does not contain what you are looking for. The reason? I don't know.

Since the URL provided does work in a browser, I simply added the `User-Agent` headers to the call, and your code started to work. To add the `User-Agent`, you would do something like:

```
from requests import get
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'}
url = 'https://www.oddsportal.com/soccer/spain/laliga/'
response = get(url, headers=headers)

if response.status_code == 200:
    html_soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')
    movie_containers = html_soup.find_all('td', class_ = 'name table-participant')
    print(type(movie_containers))
    print(len(movie_containers))
else:
    print("Server returned status code %s" % response.status_code)
```

Comment: thank you so much!
I was not getting any error. How do you get see the 404 error?

Comment: @Lander After doing `response = get(url)` I checked `response.status_code` and found out it was `404` instead of `200`.